# Dynamic width of div based on value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to change the width of a div depending on some calculated value from 0-100 I get as a variable. What I do now is just:

```
<div style="width: {{widthDivFunction()}}%"></div>
```

And this works. But in VSCode this actually gives an indication of error (i.e. the component is red) saying `property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected)`.

I am unaware if this is the way to do this, and I just need to ignore the red component, or if there actually is a better way to do this ?

Comment: I found a solution in this issue, maybe it works for you ? https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/872

Comment: You seem to be missing the closing quote of your `style` attribute (I’m assuming that’s a typo in your question, and not in your code), along with a third closing curly-brace, and a closing tag with a percent sign. This may just be angular syntax though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was a typo. @LeonardoBezerra, this is basically the code that gives the red error. If I change the `{{widthDivFunction()}}%` with some fixed value, e.g. `50%` there are no errors. But I think this error occurs because, at least VSCode, doesn't like inline CSS with JS - which is basically the case.

Comment: I don't think this is a VSCode issue, it might be your linter ? I use css inline but I use React and Vue, never used Angular, sorry. What I would do is maybe try a getter for that case instead of inserting the width directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div [style.width.%]="widthDivFunction()">blah</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngStyle` for dynamic styling.

Store dynamic width value in a variable and use with ngStyle

> Example

```
[ngStyle]="{ with: VARIABLE + 'px' }"
```